# C++ Template Method Type Constrained

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, children, assertion

I have to create a template function, which its T value is child of a base class (Actor). In C# it is done like this:

```
//C#
public T Create<T>() where T : Actor
{
}
```

If you take a look at the C# MSD ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)):

> The **where** clause in a generic definition specifies constraints on
>   the types that are used as arguments for type parameters in a generic
>   type, method, delegate, or local function. [[...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)]

So, I tried this into my C++ code but I was wondering to find other ways to make it. Something more noticeable that doesn't allow you to give this function an unsupported value and/or, in case you do it, you detect the error easily. This way isn't working fine for me.

```
//C++
template<typename T>
T* Create()
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Actor, T>::value, L"T must inherit from Actor");

    //Some code
    return actor;
}
```

Thanks in advance and a greeting!

Comment: Can you state what exactly is not working? Does it compile? Or not do what you want?

Comment: Looks okay to me? What's wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what is doing. The project does not compile, but the console error is not clear (Nowhere it says the message I wrote), so if somebody gets my code and tries to enter an unsupported value, I don't think I'd know what's wrong.

Comment: When in C# you type an unsupported value the line becomes red underlined, so you know that what you typed is wrong. I think that is impossible here, but I'm searching for something who makes the error can find what is wrong.

Comment: You're going to have to tell us what the error is then... ideally with a [mcve] so that we can reproduce it and work on it.

Comment: How do you know the project didn't compile? The compiler must have said *something*.

Comment: Error C2002 invalid wide-character constant (compiling source file ExampleGame.cpp)

Comment: Right, so you typed `L'...'` not `L"..."`. Not in the question, though, so we couldn't have guessed that!

Comment: When you start building the project it gets this error, what it's okay, but not a clear error.

Comment: That's because it's an error completely unrelated to bases and templates. It's related to wide-character constants (i.e. character literals that look like `L'...'`)

Comment: No, I typed what is in the code shown in the question: L"T must inherit from Actor". Or I'm not understanding you?

Comment: Produce a [mcve] please so that we can reproduce it, then, because [your code works for me](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edbe765ae2ddfe4f), and there is no reason I'm aware of for it to give the error you report on any platform.

Comment: Okay, I reproduced what I have in my project [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fb583c3cc05f42b). I don't know what is going on but here it works... Taking a deep look at my project, I'm seeing that the compiler seems to ignore the assert or something like that, because what is giving me the error is a function called in the Create method (who is saying me that can't receive that parameter) but not the assert itself. What you see in the link is exactly what I have.

Comment: What you have in the link gives exactly what you wanted as the first error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got something that makes exactly what I was searching for. It gives you the information on real-time of the error without having to build the solution. It is the most similar thing to C# I found. How works for you too.

```
//T must inherit from Actor
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Actor, T>::value, T*>::type Create()
{
    //Some code
    return actor;
}
```

You can find more information about the std::enable_if [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/enable_if/).

In addition, I have to say that the previous code wrote in the question worked fine for the people who have helped me, so maybe is a good solution for you.